# Web Service cycle using Contract-First in Java

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm working on an application with contract first web services (`wsimport` and `jaxws-maven-plugin`).

How should I write WSDL/XSD files in order to be able to process cycles? For example object `department` with reference to `employees` and `employee` with reference to `department` (as in this article http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_cyclic_references_to_XML.html ). The article notes a `@XmlTransient` annotation, but as I use contract-first, I'm unable to modify generated classes in any way.

If I just ignore those cycles, first time I run the webservice, I receive an error such as:

```
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: 
A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: 
Employee@18ac4d8 -> Department@aa35d5 -> Employee@18ac4d8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that webservice contracts (at least WS-I Basic Profile compliant ones) can not encode references to other objects in the message. That is, a field of reference type is always marshalled by marshalling the fields of the object it refers to. This recursion is limitless if the object graph contains a cycle.

That is, if you had:

```
class A {
    String name;
    A a;
}
```

and did:

```
A a = new A();
a.name = "hello";
a.a = a;
marshall(a);
```

The XML would look like

```
<a>
    <name>hello</name>
    <a>
        <name>hello</name>
        <a>
            <name>hello</name>
            <a>
                ...
```

To avoid this, the cycle needs to be broken. Typical approaches include to make the association navigable in only one direction, set backreferences to `null` prior to marshalling (tasking the recipient to reconstruct them), move the associations to seperate classes like in

```
class A {
    String name;
}
class B {
    String adress;   
}

class AWithB {
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

and a host of other options.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this is one way to solve the problem, but it requires extra code on both sides of communication (server must break the reference and client reconstruct it).

I've tried to look into @XmlID/@XmlIDREF, which enables cyclic references, but it converts objects into Object class and requires manual typecasting on client side as well..

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks for pointing out xs:id and xs:idref.